# Is it possible to set the sender address dynamically in nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send myself emails from a contact form as part of my application. I have it set up with SendPulse as an SMTP server. I would like to create the message like so:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
  {
    service: 'SendPulse',
    auth: {
      user: 'myemail@myemail.com',
      pass: 'mypassword'
    }
  }
);

app.post('/send-message', (req, res) => {
  transporter.sendMail(
    {
      from: req.body.email,
      to: 'myemail@myemail.com',
      subject: req.body.subject,
      text: req.body.message,
      html: `<p>${req.body.message}</p>`
    },
    (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(info);
      };
    }
  );
});
```

The problem is that unless `req.body.email` is the same as `myemail@myemail.com` registered on the transporter, I get the error:

```
{
  code: "EENVELOPE",
  response: "554 5.9.2 Sender domain is not valid.",
  responseCode: 554, command: "MAIL FROM"
}
```

Is there any way that I can set the `from` property to whatever is input in the contact form?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the domain of the sender email address is not valid by the SendPulse verification during the email send process.

This can be caused by missing configuration in your domain's DNS. You have probably a missing SPF record.

> Create an SPF record so that more of your emails get to the recipients' inboxes. The receiving mail servers will use the SPF record to confirm that the email is sent from your domain.

You should add the `TXT` record to your DNS settings in your domain, as [described here](https://login.sendpulse.com/manual/smtp-spf/) with the following value:

```
v=spf1 include:mxsmtp.sendpulse.com +a +mx ~all
```

If it does't work, make sure that you are allowed to send emails, because maybe your account is blocked from sending emails up until you are verified.
Contact SendPulse support to find out.

Answer (score 0):

After facing same issue. I switched to this solution. Used sendPulse API using npm package.

below is the code and link

```
   var sendpulse = require("sendpulse-api");
/*
 * https://login.sendpulse.com/settings/#api
 */
var API_USER_ID = "USER_ID";
var API_SECRET = "USER_SECRET";
var TOKEN_STORAGE = "/tmp/";
 
sendpulse.init(API_USER_ID,API_SECRET,TOKEN_STORAGE,function() {
    sendpulse.listAddressBooks(console.log);
});
 var answerGetter = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

var email = {
  "html" : "<h1>Example text</h1>",
  "text" : "Example text",
  "subject" : "Example subject",
  "from" : {
    "name" : "Alex",
    "email" : "some@domain.com"
  },
  "to" : [
    {
      "name" : "Piter",
      "email" : "some@domain.net"
    },
  ],
  "bcc" : [
    {
      "name" : "John",
      "email" : "some@domain.info"
    },
  ]
};
sendpulse.smtpSendMail(answerGetter,email);

/*   */
```

[For complete detail visit this site.](https://github.com/sendpulse/sendpulse-rest-api-node.js)